# Axios get with params not working on frontend, postman working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, request

I'm trying to get som data from database, on frontend I'm using axios and my request is:

```
  const getAllPayments = async () =>

    {
      const { data } = await Axios.get("payment_query/allPayments.php", {
        params: {
          company_id: 1,
          year: 2022,
          start_mounth: 1,
          end_mounth: 12,
        },
      });
      if (data) {
        console.log(data);
        setPayments(data);
        setWait(false);
        return true;
      }
      setPayments([]);
    };
```

When I try to send request via postman everything working
here is json body:

```
{
      "company_id": 1,
      "year" : 2022,
     "start_mounth" : 1,
     "end_mounth" : 12
}
```

Can anyone think of what could be wrong with that?

Comment: You sure you want a GET request with query params? The postman screenshot looks more like a POST request body

Comment: Axios sends HTTP requests, therefore, you must specify the URL to where the request should be sent. In your case, the URL is incorrect.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

GET requests don't work with body, they work with search params. Check to see if Axios is using POST for it's request or make sure your endpoint is expecting a get request and not a POST request.